# How to create new list from existing list taking first n-5 elements?

Tags: c++, stl

How to create new std::list from existing std::list taking first n-5 elements ?
n is size of existing list (list)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
std::list<T> newlist(oldlist.begin(), std::prev(oldlist.end(), 5));
```

where `T` is the value type of the old list.

`std::prev` is new in C++11, but if you don't have it you can use `std::advance` instead:

```
std::list<T>::const_iterator end = oldlist.end();
std::advance(end, -5);
std::list<T> newlist(oldlist.begin(), end);
```

Either way it's your responsibility to ensure that `oldlist.size() >= 5`. Neither `std::prev` nor `std::advance` does that for you.